# concat two arrays in JS with a string at index 0 in first array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

the point here is to join two arrays and ultimately calculate the amplitude. the console logs error error, followed by NaN.. what am I doing wrong? If i move the error element in the first array to the middle of the array, this works fine. it also works if i concat the first array to the second array, but i would like to make this work as similarly as the way it is written below.

```js
const temperatures = ['error', 3, -2, -6, -1, 9, 13, 17, 15, 14, 9, 5];
const temperatures2 = [45, 23, 12, 2, 4, 6, 9, 78, 13, 15];

const tempMerge = temperatures.concat(temperatures2);

const calcTempAmplitude = function (temps) {
    let max = temps[0];
    let min = temps[0];

    for (let i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
        const currTemp = temps[i];

        if (typeof currTemp !== 'number') {
            continue;
        }

        if (temps[i] > max) {
            max = currTemp;
        }
        if (temps[i] < min) {
            min = currTemp;
        }
    }
    console.log(max, min);
    return max - min;
};
const amplitude = calcTempAmplitude(tempMerge);
console.log(amplitude);
```

Comment: `let max = temps[0];` `let min = temps[0];` isn't going to work if you start with a non-number

Answer (score 0):

Try using the spread operator:

```
const amp = Math.max(...temperatures, ...temperatures2) - Math.min(...temperatures, ...temperatures2);
```

EDIT:

Filter the arrays for only numbers:

```
const amp = Math.max(...temperatures.filter(x => typeof x === "number"), ...temperatures2.filter(x => typeof x === "number")) - Math.min(...temperatures.filter(x => typeof x === "number"), ...temperatures2.filter(x => typeof x === "number"));
```

Comment: The result of this is `NaN` because the maximum or minimum of a number and a string is `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I don't know what output you are expecting, but by modifying the code of line no. 3, I am able to get the output **"84"**.

Here is the **line no. 3 code:**

```
const tempMerge = temperatures.filter(temp => typeof temp === 'number').concat(temperatures2);
```

What I did is just filtered out non-number data from **'temperatures'** variable.

Here is the full running code on JSBin: https://jsbin.com/dofoxuf/edit?js,console

Comment: thank you! that is the correct output. amplitude is calculating the difference between the highest temp and the lowest, which in this case is 78 and -6.